# Terse NGINX config for numerous nearly-identical sites

Tags: nginx

I have a NGINX web server on which I host numerous small websites. Each website has a unique domain name (with or without a subdomain), an HTML file and a PHP file and has identical configuration. The only differences for each site are:

1. Domain name - `example.com`
2. Some simple HTML - `<title>Example Site</title>`
3. File path on server - `/usr/share/nginx/example.com/html`

So far I have been adding a server block file for each site and this has worked well. However, the process is tedious and I am copy-pasting lots of boilerplate config. I am getting more and more sites on the server and the process isn't as scalable as I would like. Since everything is so similar, I'd like to be able to define the config once and never have to worry about it again.

Is there a terse way of configuring multiple sites to serve from separate subfolders? E.G. I would point Nginx at `/usr/share/nginx/` and it would automatically choose the `example.com` subfolder based on the `example.com` domain in the HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the map module http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

It was designed for such a requirement

Answer (score 2):

Put your common configuration in one file and use [include](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) from a site specific configuration. This will reduce the configuration required.

This isn't quite what you asked, but it would make things a bit easier.